# Connect viewmodel class to adapter(recyclerview)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, viewmodel

I have viewModel class which name UserListViewModel And on that class there is function which named sumUserIncrease and I want to get that functions value and send that to adapter to show in recyclerview I hope you got what I mean if not, take look at this:

here is my userListViewModel:

```
class UserListViewModel(
val mUserInfoDAO: UserDAO,
val mTransactionDAO: TransactionsDAO,
val mLoanDAO: LoanDAO,
val mBankDAO: BankDAO,
application: Application
) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {
    var viewModelJob = Job()
    val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)
    fun sumAllIncrease(id: Long): Long {
        return mTransactionDAO.sumUserIncrease(id)
    }

    fun sumAllDecrease(id: Long): Long {
        return mTransactionDAO.sumUserDecrease(id)
    }
}
```

my Adapter:

```
 package com.example.holyquran.ui.userList
class UserAdapter() : ListAdapter<UserInfo, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(BillDiffCallback()) {
    private val ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY = 0

    private val ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 1
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        return when (viewType) {
            ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM -> ViewHolder.from(parent)
            ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY -> EmptyViewHolder.from(parent)
            else -> throw ClassCastException("Unknown viewType $viewType")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is ViewHolder -> {
                val item = getItem(position)
                holder.bind(item, clickListener)
            }
            is EmptyViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind()
            }
        }
    }

    lateinit var clickListener: AdapterListener
    fun setOnclickListener(listener: AdapterListener) {
        clickListener = listener
    }


    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (itemCount > 0)
            ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM
        else
            ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY
    }

    class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ItemUserListBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: UserInfo, adapterListener: AdapterListener) {





            if (item.gender == "مرد") {
                binding.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_avata_male);
            }else{
                binding.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_avatar_female);
            }

            binding.userInfo = item
            binding.clickListener = adapterListener
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ItemUserListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }

    class EmptyViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ItemUserListBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind() {
            binding.executePendingBindings()


        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): EmptyViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ItemUserListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return EmptyViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }
}

class BillDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<UserInfo>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: UserInfo, newItem: UserInfo): Boolean {
        return oldItem.userId == newItem.userId
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(
        oldItem: UserInfo,
        newItem: UserInfo
    ): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

class AdapterListener(
    val clickListener: (id: Long) -> Unit,
    val deleteListener: (userInfo: UserInfo) -> Unit,
    private val longClickListener: (id: Long) -> Unit

) {
    fun onclick(userInfo: UserInfo) = clickListener(userInfo.userId)
    fun onDeleteClick(userInfo: UserInfo) = deleteListener(userInfo)
    fun onLongClick(userInfo: UserInfo) = longClickListener(userInfo.userId)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your `UserListViewModel` contain `LiveData` that your `Fragment/Activity` observes. Once it gets an update it will send it to the `Adapter`.

In `ViewModel`

```
private val currentSum : MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(0)

fun sumAllIncrease(id: Long): Long {
    var sum = mTransactionDAO.sumUserIncrease(id)
    currentSum.value = sum
    return sum
}
fun sumAllDecrease(id: Long): Long {
    var sum = mTransactionDAO.sumUserDecrease(id)
    currentSum.value = sum
    return sum
}
fun getCurrentSum(): LiveData<Long> {
    return currentSum
}
```

In `Fragment/Activity`

```
viewModel.getCurrentSum().observe(this, Observer {
    adapter.setSum(it)
})
```

In `Adapter`

```
fun setSum(sum : Long){
    //The sum is now in you adapter.
    //Use it how you need too.
}
```

But this is kinda unusual. What you really want to do is pass a new `UserInfo` with the changed sum. And let the `DiffCallback` change the one that is different. What you probably want to do is implement `Paging` https://proandroiddev.com/paging-3-easier-way-to-pagination-part-1-584cad1f4f61   This will allow you to change stuff in the database anywhere in the app. When that happens the data will be updated in the `Adapter`. Its kinda complex but once you get it working you want regret it.

Comment: Thanks @avalerio but there is one more thing that I need to do

Comment: I want to show sum of each user's increase in recycler view. When I use sumUserIncrease It returns same amount for all items.I have a user list and I show them in recycler view and in recycler view of course we have a xml mine named itemUserList and on that xml I want to show for example sum of user1 increase. I hope you got what I try to say

Comment: So paging is my solution? isn't it?

Comment: It looks like your using `Room`. If so you will need to make a `data` class that represent the combination of the users transactions and the users info. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#kotlin Lets call it `UserInfoWithTransactions` You will then need to display that in your `RecyclerView` instead of just `UserInfo`. That way you will have both when you bind to the `ViewHolder`. By using `Paging3`, a change to the `Transactions` table will auto pull a fresh list of `UserInfoWithTransactions` (containing the new Transactions).

Comment: So it is something like join in room database?